# Is it possible to split a polyline into three equal segments that are rounded down to the nearest integer without allocating the remaining amount?

Tags: arcgis-pro, line, splitting

I need to split polylines that are over 900m into three equal segments. I need the segment lengths to be integers that are rounded down without the remaining amount being allocated to either the last feature in the sequence or distributed equally to each feature.

I would prefer to work in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want, but it's certainly possible. The uselessness of this information is the reason Questions need to specifically detail what is needed, and explain what you have attempted, and where you are stuck. A diagram which clearly shows the goal is going to be the first critical step.

Answer (score 1):

I would say any question like this and the FIRST place you should be looking at is the ESRI Code Sharing website. Searching for simple words like split, divide or segment threw up:

- [Divide line by length](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d5d27ee47330434b9a96b91136a0118f)
- [Points Along Line](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=afb3cb8727c54ceba30c1df1c734f97a)

Of course if you look at the help file you would have found

- [Split Line at Point](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-point.htm)
- [Generate Points Along Lines](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/generate-points-along-lines.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Edit sessions in ArcGIS pro include a tool called [Divide](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/divide-a-polyline-by-a-value.htm).  In Divide you can divide a selected line by a user-defined distance, equal parts, or percentages.  If your total line length is an integer then fine - divide into equal parts.  Otherwise you are going to have to calculate the length of the undivide line, use divide by distance at your desired integer values, then divide the third remaining line accordingly and delete the non-integer remainder.